# launchd does run but script is not executed?

Tags: php, osx-elcapitan, launchd

I have looked for answers here but could not find them.
So my issue is the following:
I have created a launchd like this: com.schedule.arp.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
    <string>com.schedule.arp.plist</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/Library/Scripts/arp.sh</string>
</array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>300</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I can see the it runs every 5 minutes like it should. here is the console:

Apr 21 09:46:39 eps-amsterdam com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.schedule.arp.plist[2946]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Apr 21 09:51:39 eps-amsterdam com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.schedule.arp.plist[3274]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Apr 21 09:56:39 eps-amsterdam com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.schedule.arp.plist[3554]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Apr 21 10:01:39 eps-amsterdam com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.schedule.arp.plist[4156]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1

The actual script is here:/Library/Scripts/arp.sh
it contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo php56 /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/epsamsterdam/arpreach_full/a.php cli/auto
```

But this last part is not executed?
Manual hitting this command in terminal runs fine.
So where do I go wrong?
I'm running at El Capitan 10.11.4

Comment: I have it solved by editing the arp.sh script. To use full paths. So it looks like this: #!/bin/sh /opt/local/bin/php56 /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/epsamsterdam/arpreach_full/a.php cli/auto